Why doesn't d3 like this GeoJSON file?
Does anyone have any idea why D3 is failing to render the following GeoJSON?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <svg width="960" height="720"></svg>
  <div id='neighborhoodPopover'> </div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-array@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo-projection@4"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

const nycGeoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "neighborhood": "Hamilton Heights",
        "boroughCode": null,
        "borough": null,
        "@id": null
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -73.96083942042421,
              40.81944719738439
            ],
            [
              -73.95280837990867,
              40.81581771326914
            ],
            [
              -73.9527010915481,
              40.81654806965256
            ],
            [
              -73.95171403863061,
              40.8179276097718
            ],
            [
              -73.95072698571312,
              40.81844695861872
            ],
            [
              -73.94803047114694,
              40.8221363829966
            ],
            [
              -73.94612073832833,
              40.82127625710196
            ],
            [
              -73.94475459746901,
              40.82419761694012
            ],
            [
              -73.94385337524001,
              40.82387305252829
            ],
            [
              -73.93918905697315,
              40.82999573657146
            ],
            [
              -73.948905,
              40.83406600000012
            ],
            [
              -73.949342,
              40.833982
            ],
            [
              -73.95015520996616,
              40.83439675981593
            ],
            [
              -73.95725896977153,
              40.82711730987318
            ],
            [
              -73.96127700238141,
              40.82169843098817
            ],
            [
              -73.96083942042421,
              40.81944719738439
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": 169
    }
  ]
};

const projection = 
        d3.geoAlbers()
          .fitSize([width, height], nycGeoJson);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);


svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(nycGeoJson.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)


</script>
</body>



It's rendering as the following, which is not the correct path:

It should look like this instead:

There are a number of other features from the original map that render the same way, so I think it is some artifact related to the way d3 is rendering this map data, but I can't identify what is causing D3 to render it this way. Other map rendering libraries do not have an issue rendering this GeoJSON data.
I would appreciate any insight anyone could share on this. Thank you for your time and attention to this.

Winding order is likely off, see here or here

Multiple edits later: Your GeoDataJSON is correct as it specifies the coordinates in order:

longitude
latitude

In short: If you reverse the coordinate order you can see the expected result.
//reverse coordinates
let coord = nycGeoJson.features[0].geometry.coordinates.map(item=>{return item.reverse()})




var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

let nycGeoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "neighborhood": "Hamilton Heights",
        "boroughCode": null,
        "borough": null,
        "@id": null
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -73.96083942042421,
              40.81944719738439
            ],
            [
              -73.95280837990867,
              40.81581771326914
            ],
            [
              -73.9527010915481,
              40.81654806965256
            ],
            [
              -73.95171403863061,
              40.8179276097718
            ],
            [
              -73.95072698571312,
              40.81844695861872
            ],
            [
              -73.94803047114694,
              40.8221363829966
            ],
            [
              -73.94612073832833,
              40.82127625710196
            ],
            [
              -73.94475459746901,
              40.82419761694012
            ],
            [
              -73.94385337524001,
              40.82387305252829
            ],
            [
              -73.93918905697315,
              40.82999573657146
            ],
            [
              -73.948905,
              40.83406600000012
            ],
            [
              -73.949342,
              40.833982
            ],
            [
              -73.95015520996616,
              40.83439675981593
            ],
            [
              -73.95725896977153,
              40.82711730987318
            ],
            [
              -73.96127700238141,
              40.82169843098817
            ],
            [
              -73.96083942042421,
              40.81944719738439
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": 169
    }
  ]
};


//reverse coordinates
let coord = nycGeoJson.features[0].geometry.coordinates.map(item=>{return item.reverse()})

const projection = 
        d3.geoAlbers()
          .fitSize([width, height], nycGeoJson);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);


svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(nycGeoJson.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
  <svg width="960" height="720"></svg>
  <div id='neighborhoodPopover'> </div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-array@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo-projection@4"></script>



Leaflet example


let pt = {
  lat: 40.81944719738439,
  lon: -73.96083942042421
};

let map = L.map('map', {
  /**
   * 1. longitude 2. latitude
   **/
  center: [pt.lat, pt.lon],
  zoom: 5
});


// Create a Tile Layer and add it to the map
let tiles = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

let marker = L.marker(
  [pt.lat, pt.lon], {
    draggable: true,
    title: "",
  });

marker.addTo(map);
#map { 
  width:100%;
  aspect-ratio:16/9;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="map"></div>



Unfortunately, there is a lot of (perfectly unnecessary) confusion about the correct order as expected by APIs:
Speculative: Probably the main reason for this confusion is the expected alphabetic order of property names – so lat should be before lon/lng - right? No it's not!
If we remember the meaning of these values with regards to the 2 dimensional projection it makes perfect sense:

longitude values correspond to the x-axis (east to west: also referred to as eastings)
latitude represents the y-axis (north to south) in a 2-demensional projection (aka northings)

However it's kind of a running gag the incorrect order is frequently required by a lot of API's if not the defacto standard.
